# Python Flask Authenticaton without a Database

Tags: python, database, authentication, flask

I'm attempting to simplify a Flask project by eliminating the use of any database. This will eliminate the need to use SQLAlchemy.

I'm having trouble duplicating the same login mechanism that exist with verifying the username and passwords that I learned about in a Flask tutorial.

I found some example code on-line and attempted to combine the two. I've read as much of the documentation as I can but I am left scratching my head about extracting a valid UserMixin object as this is required to login to the Flask app when using the Flask.Login extension.

I would be eternally grateful if someone could help me overcome my code deficiencies below to get them working well together.

Here is the view:

```
from flask import render_template, redirect, request, url_for, flash
from flask.ext.login import login_user, logout_user, login_required
from . import auth
from .forms import LoginForm
from ..models import User, load_user

@auth.route('/login', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
    user = User.get(form.userName.data)
    user = load_user(user)
    if user is not None:
        login_user(user, form.remember_me.data)
        flash('You are now logged in!')
        return redirect(request.args.get('next') or url_for('main.index'))
    flash('Invalid username or password')
return render_template('auth/login.html', form=form)
```

Here is the model:

```
from flask.ext.login import UserMixin
from . import login_manager

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user):
    return User.get(user)

class User(UserMixin):

# proxy for a database of users
user_database = {u"user": (u"user", u"password"),u"admin": (u"admin", u"password")}

def __init__(self, username, password):
    self.id = username
    self.password = password

@classmethod
def get(cls,userName):
    return cls.user_database.get(userName)
```

The problem is that I cannot find a way to instantiate the user object correctly to work with the other Flask Login methods. I keep getting errors not matter what variation of the code I do.

Comment: What problem(s) are you having?

Comment: You need to write a `verify_password()` method in your `User` class.

Comment: I believe the question boils down to this: How do I get load_user to return a user object that works with login_user(user) by modifying the code above?